# Remote debug of Rust program in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, remote-debugging

I am developing a Rust program to run on an embedded Linux board that is based on a 64-bit ARM processor. The embedded Linux for the target is built using Yocto (dunfell). My Rust development environment is Visual Studio Code running on Linux (Ubuntu). How can I set it up to do remote debugging of the program on the target board?

I expect the sequence would be something like:

- Compile the Rust program for the target (for debug).
- Copy the debug bin file to the target.
- Run it on the target, using gdbserver or lldb-server.
- VS Code connects to the remote gdb/lldb, and controls the program for the usual debug.

Answer (score 9):

#### Extensions

- I'm using the **rust-analyzer** extension for code analysis. It is better than the **Rust** extension.
- **CodeLLDB** extension to enable debugging of a Rust program, using lldb.

#### Cross-compiling

The target board has a 64-bit ARM processor, so I want to use Rust to cross-compile for target `aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu`.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (it is old, but I have to use it to support an old project built with an old Yocto version). I used `apt` to install Ubuntu package `gcc-8-aarch64-linux-gnu`. On a more recent Ubuntu perhaps I could install a more modern package such as `gcc-11-aarch64-linux-gnu`.

In my `~/.cargo/config`:

```
[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu]
linker = "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-8"
```

Then, I can manually use `cargo` to cross-compile using the command:

```
cargo build --target=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Then to cross-compile within VS Code — In my VS Code workspace for myapp, in `.vscode/tasks.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "tasks": [
        ...
        {
            "label": "rust: cargo build ARM"
            "type": "cargo",
            "command": "build",
            "args": ["--target=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu"],
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$rustc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
        },
    ]
}
```

Then I just do Shift-Ctrl-B, and select the "rust: cargo build ARM" build task.

#### Remote debugging

The goal is to run `myapp` on `targetboard.local` as low-privileges user `targetuser` (rather than root).

In VS Code, the CodeLLDB extension uses lldb to debug Rust programs. But, lldb is a large compilation in Yocto for the target hardware. But, it works fine to connect to `gdbserver` running on the target board. The embedded Linux image running on the target board just needs to have `gdbserver` on it.

The target board also needs to have an SSH server running on it, with support for either `rsync` or plain SSH copy. `rsync` is good because it can be faster to do the copy of the executable to the target.

In my VS Code workspace for myapp, in `.vscode/launch.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "configurations": [
        ...
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "custom",
            "name": "Remote executable 'myapp'",
            "preLaunchTask": "rust: remote ARM debug setup",
            "targetCreateCommands": ["target create ${workspaceFolder}/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/myapp"],
            "processCreateCommands": ["gdb-remote targetboard.local:17777"]
        }
    ]
}
```

In my VS Code workspace for myapp, in `.vscode/tasks.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "tasks": [
        ...
        {
            "label": "rust: remote ARM debug setup",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${workspaceFolder}/scripts/remote_debug.sh",
            "args": [ "${workspaceFolder}", "targetboard.local", "17777" ],
            "group": "none",
            "dependsOn": [
                "rust: cargo build ARM",
            ],
        },
    ]
}
```

In my VS Code workspace for myapp, I created the script `scripts/remote_debug.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

VSCODE_WS="$1"
SSH_REMOTE="$2"
GDBPORT="$3"

APP="myapp"
TARGET_ARCH="aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu"
BUILD_BIN_FILE="${VSCODE_WS}/target/${TARGET_ARCH}/debug/${APP}"
TARGET_USER="targetuser"
TARGET_BIN_FILE="/home/targetuser/${APP}"
TARGET_CWD="/var/lib/myapp"

ssh "${TARGET_USER}@${SSH_REMOTE}" "killall gdbserver ${APP}"

if ! rsync -avz "${BUILD_BIN_FILE}" "${TARGET_USER}@${SSH_REMOTE}:${TARGET_BIN_FILE}"; then
    # If rsync doesn't work, it may not be available on target. Fallback to trying SSH copy.
    if ! scp "${BUILD_BIN_FILE}" "${TARGET_USER}@${SSH_REMOTE}:${TARGET_BIN_FILE}"; then
        exit 2
    fi
fi

ssh -f "${TARGET_USER}@${SSH_REMOTE}" "sh -c 'cd ${TARGET_CWD}; nohup gdbserver *:${GDBPORT} ${TARGET_BIN_FILE} > /dev/null 2>&1 &'"
```

The target CWD `/var/lib/myapp` needs to exist with the right user permissions for `targetuser`. I could just specify `/home/targetuser` instead.

With that set up, I can just press F5 in VS Code, and it will compile, copy the file to the target board, and start remote-debugging it through `gdbserver`.

Comment: Very nice! The script is actually not needed and can be defined as 3 tasks as well (the gdbserver kill, the exe copy & the gdbserver start).

Comment: @jaques-sam Thank you for the tip. I'll see if I can improve/simplify my setup.