# Remote debug of Rust program in Visual Studio Code where VSCode sits on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, remote-debugging

dear Craig McQueen!

I am referring to: [Remote debug of Rust program in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68888706/remote-debug-of-rust-program-in-visual-studio-code/70572503#70572503)

My config is slightly different that is why I cannot get everything going here:

1. VScode installed on WIN32 with RUST components successfully!
2. remote system: odroid C2 ARM64 with UBUNTU18.04 with Kernel 5.14nwith IP: 192.xxx.6.x - user odroid.
3. I need to remote-compile a Rust program called: c2_mmap_gpio on the OdroidC2
   This is already a project on the WIN32.

I did all the steps but it doesn't work.

1. I think it is not possible to try to run a remote_debug.sh (bash) on a windows machine, right? If yes workaround on this?
2. I think I need to input my user PWD somewhere to be able to ssh into the remote linux machine, right?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Correct, the `remote_debug.sh` I [described in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68888706/remote-debug-of-rust-program-in-visual-studio-code/68888707#68888707) is good only for a Linux system, and not suitable for a Windows system. For a Windows development system, you would need to write a Windows batch file or Powershell script that provides the equivalent functionality to that `remote_debug.sh` Bash script.
   I'm not proficient in Powershell scripts, and I'm happy using Linux
   as my host development machine, so I don't have plans to write such a script.
2. Regarding needing to enter a password for the SSH operations... Good point. That's something I didn't think to mention in my answer. You need to remove the need for a password to be entered, in one of two ways:

   - Install your public SSH credentials onto the target, using `ssh-copy-id` (or the Windows equivalent). Then you should be able to SSH to the target without needing to enter your password.
   - Give a blank password to the target user on the target, using `passwd -d <username>`. Note this reduces security, so this is not recommended, especially if the target is accessible via the public Internet.